# Graphics driver for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, amd-graphics

My laptop is a Toshiba Tecra M9, running Ubuntu 12.04. When I unplug my laptop from charger it freezes and I cannot do anything. I need to restart it every time to get it to work correctly again.When I installed addition driver from system settings it didn't freeze anymore, but it takes lot of time to switch between windows and opening gedit windows. Is this a problem with my graphics driver? Can anybody please help me to find right graphics driver for my laptop.

In settings it shows my current graphics driver is Quadro NVS 130M/PCI/SSE2

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 Linux drivers, the privative and the open driver, you have the open driver installed try to install the privative driver. It's better if before uninstalling the video driver before install the new driver,

Try to reinstall the Xorg driver on a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo aptitude reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel 
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Install MESA:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

So, if you want to know what driver are using use:

```
glxinfo | grep -i render
```

Here how install the Linux video driver for Ubuntu:

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.2-linux

After install the video driver is good make  a actualization:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

NOTE: Sometimes the the privative drivers works better than the open driver, but try with them.

Here are a very good video tutorial to win more speed on Ubuntu

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwBoHZuauL8